# Magento 2: Save custom customer attribute value programmatically

Tags: magento2, customer, customer-attribute

How can I save a custom **Customer Attribute** value programmatically?
I have tried below code but it didn't work.

```
protected $customer;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer $customer
)
{
    $this->customer = $customer;
}

...
...

$customerId = "1";
$customer = $this->customer->load($customerId);
$data = "customer attribute value";
$customerData = $customer->getDataModel();
$customerData->setCustomAttribute('customer_attribute_code',$data);
$customer->updateData($customerData);
$customer->save();
```

Is there any other method to save the customer attribute?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I have got the solution

```
protected $customer;

protected $customerFactory;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer $customer,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerFactory $customerFactory
)
{
    $this->customer = $customer;
    $this->customerFactory = $customerFactory;
}

...
...

$customerId = "1";
$customer = $this->customer->load($customerId);
$data = "customer attribute value";
$customerData = $customer->getDataModel();
$customerData->setCustomAttribute('customer_attribute_code',$data);
$customer->updateData($customerData);
$customerResource = $this->customerFactory->create();
$customerResource->saveAttribute($customer, 'customer_attribute_code');
```

Comment: This code not working in magento 2.2.3, please suggest if you have any alternate solution please share as I want to save custom customer address attribute value programmatically.

Comment: @Dinesh , Best Solution ever I got. Working for all types of `customer attributes`.

Comment: @TBSMage, Thank you for your valuable comment :)

Comment: I have created attribute of type int, that is not saving if i use below code
$customerData->setCustomAttribute('customer_check', 1);

Comment: @DineshYadav, how to save customer custom address values?

Comment: hello, thanks for the answer it does work, but the custom attribute value doesn't show up in customer grid, I had to reindex manuelly

Answer (score 7):

You need to do it the strange Magento 2 way:-

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository,
) {
    $this->_customerRepository = $customerRepository;
}

public function execute()
{
    $customer = $this->_customerRepository->getById($customerId);
    $customer->setDob($data['dob'])
             ->setCustomAttribute('medicare_number',$data['medicare_number'])
             ->setCustomAttribute('medicare_reference',$data['medicare_reference'])
             ->setCustomAttribute('medicare_exp',$data['medicare_exp']);
    $this->_customerRepository->save($customer);
}
```

Comment: Using this approach, you will get exceptions when you save the customer when the customer's address is not complete. For example, no street address, region, etc.

Comment: how about if you have a custom multiselect attribute ?

Answer (score 1):

Some times, you may need to save **multiple attributes** at the same time. After go through the Magento code, I endup with this code. Here **medicare_number** and **medicare_reference** are custom attributes.

```
        $customerModel = $this->_customerFactory->create();
        $customerModel->getResource()->load($customerModel, $customerId);
        $customerModel->setData('dob', $this->getRequest()->getParam('dob'))
                    ->setData('gender', $this->getRequest()->getParam('gender'))
                    ->setData('medicare_number', $this->getRequest()->getParam('medicare_number'))
                    ->setData('medicare_reference', $this->getRequest()->getParam('medicare_reference'))
                    ->setAttributeSetId(\Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerMetadataInterface::ATTRIBUTE_SET_ID_CUSTOMER);
        $customerModel->getResource()->save($customerModel);
```

Comment: this is working in 2.2.5, tried dozens of other answers but none of them work, thank you!

Comment: short version for working code is something like `$customer->setData('my_attribute', 1234)                    ->setAttributeSetId(\Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerMetadataInterface::ATTRIBUTE_SET_ID_CUSTOMER)->getResource()->save($customer)`

Answer (score 0):

```
protected $customer;

protected $customerFactory;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer $customer
    \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerFactory $customerFactory
)
{
    $this->customer = $customer;
    $this->customerFactory = $customerFactory;
}

...
...
    $mobile="1234567890";
    $custom = $this->_customerFactory ->create();
    $custom = $custom->setWebsiteId($helperData->getWebsiteId());
    $custom = $custom->loadByEmail("abc123@xyz.com");

    $customerData = $custom->getDataModel();
    $customerData->setCustomAttribute('custom_attribute code', $mobile);
    $custom->updateData($customerData);

    $custom->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this helper for Magento >2.4.2

```
<?php

namespace Company\Customer\Helper;

use Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory;

class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
    protected $customerFactory;

    public function __construct(
        CustomerFactory $customerFactory
    ) {
        $this->customerFactory = $customerFactory;
    }

    public function overrideCustomAttribute($pCustomer, $attributeCode, $value)
    {
        $customer = $this->customerFactory->create()->load($pCustomer->getId());

        $customerDataModel = $customer->getDataModel();
        $customerDataModel->setCustomAttribute($attributeCode, $value);
        $customer->updateData($customerDataModel);
        $customer->save();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Refer below code: website Id is required

```
 <?php
 namespace Devji\Customer\Model;

 use Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory;
 use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
 use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;

 class UpdateCardNumber
{
/**
 * @var StoreManagerInterface
 */
protected $_storeManager;
/**
 * @var CustomerFactory
 */
protected $_customerFactory;
/**
 * @var Customer
 */
protected $_customer;

/**
 * UpdateCardNumber constructor.
 * @param CustomerFactory       $customerFactory
 * @param Customer              $customers
 * @param StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
 */
public function __construct(
    CustomerFactory $customerFactory,
    Customer $customers,
    StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
)
{
    $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    $this->_customerFactory = $customerFactory;
    $this->_customer = $customers;
}

/**
 * Update customer attribute
 */
public function updateCustomerCardNumber()
{
    try {
        $customerCollection = $this->_customer->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect("*")
            ->addAttributeToFilter(
                array(
                    array('attribute' => 'reward_card_number', 'null' => true),
                    array('attribute' => 'reward_card_number', 'eq' => ''),
                    array('attribute' => 'reward_card_number', 'eq' => 'NO FIELD')
                ),
                '',
                'left')
            ->load();
        $websiteId = $this->_storeManager->getDefaultStoreView()->getWebsiteId();
        foreach ($customerCollection as $customer) {
            if (!empty($customer->getEntityId())) {
                $customer = $this->_customerFactory->create()->load($customer->getEntityId());
                $customerDataModel = $customer->getDataModel();
                $customerDataModel->setWebsiteId($websiteId);
                $customerDataModel->setCustomAttribute('reward_card_number',
                    $this->getCardNumber($customer->getEntityId()));
                $customer->updateData($customerDataModel);
                $customer->save();
            }
        }
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
    echo "Done";
    return;
}

/**
 * Get Card number
 * @param $customerId
 * @return string
 */
public function getCardNumber($customerId){
    $year = date('y');
    $month = date('m');
    $customerId = sprintf("%010s", $customerId);

    return '99'.$year.$month.$customerId;

}
}
```