# Customer custom attribute not being saved

Tags: magento2, customer, custom-attributes, customer-attribute, eav-attributes

I'm using magento v2.5 and i tried to create customer programmatically from frontend and backend, i share the same code between frontend and backend, after customer being save then i try to save the customer custom attribute which i made, the problem is when i try to do it from frontend side it works fine, but when i try to create the customer programmatically from backend (adminhtml) the customer was saved, but the customer custom attribute not being save:

```
// \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $_customerFactory, 
// \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $_customerRepoInterface,


$customer = $this->_customerFactory->create();
$customer->setWebsiteId(1);
$customer->setFirstname($data['firstname']);
$customer->setLastname($data['lastname']);
$customer->setPassword($data['password']);
$customer->setGender($data['gender']);
$customer->setDob($data['dob']);
$customer->setEmail($data['email']);
$customer->save();
$customer = $this->_customerRepoInterface->getById($customer->getId());
$customer->setCustomAttribute('dice_sum', '23');
$customer->setCustomAttribute('place_of_birth','joan');
$this->_customerRepoInterface->save($customer);
```

but if i try to load the old customer from backend try to save the customer custom attribute, it's working fine:

```
$customer = $this->_customerRepoInterface->getById($customer->getId());
$customer->setCustomAttribute('dice_sum', '9999');
$customer->setCustomAttribute('place_of_birth','dome');
$this->_customerRepoInterface->save($customer);
```

**edit:**

i've tried to add the customer attribute from raw query but it still not working either:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); // Instance of object manager
      $resource = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
      $connection = $resource->getConnection();
      $tableName = $resource->getTableName('customer_entity_varchar');
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM " . $tableName . " WHERE attribute_id = '160' and entity_id = '".$data['customer_id']."'";
      $result = $connection->fetchAll($sql);
      if (empty($result)) {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO " . $tableName . " (attribute_id, entity_id, value) Values ('160','".$data['customer_id']."','".$data['place_of_birth']."')";
        $connection->query($sql);
      }
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM " . $tableName . " WHERE attribute_id = '135' and entity_id = '".$data['customer_id']."'";
      $result = $connection->fetchAll($sql);
      if (empty($result)) {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO " . $tableName . " (attribute_id, entity_id, value) Values ('135','".$data['customer_id']."','".$data['dice_sum']."')";
        $connection->query($sql);
      }
```

Comment: For backend system, you donot need to set use  `setCustomAttribute`,Just  like

Comment: Did you checked my answer?

Comment: Can you add $customer->save() just after  $customer->setCustomAttribute('place_of_birth','joan');

Comment: Try this  https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/200365/48571

Comment: not working either

Answer (score 0):

I am using the Data Model to save my custom customer attribute value code is given below.

```
 $customer = $this->_customerRepoInterface->getById($customer->getId())**-getDataModel();**
 $customer->setCustomAttribute('dice_sum', '9999');
 $customer->setCustomAttribute('place_of_birth','dome');
 $this->_customerRepoInterface->save($customer);
```

Answer (score -1):

### BEST SOLUTION:

If you have used **service provider** class means `RepositoryInterface`, Then I suggest to you use **service provider** for create the new customer.

```
<?php

namespace Exchanges\Test\Test;

/**
 * Description of customerCustomAttribute
 *
 */
class customerCustomAttribute {

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $customer;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface
     */
    protected $customerData;

    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customer,
    \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface $customerData      
    ) {

        $this->customerData = $customerData;
        $this->customer = $customer;
    }
    public function saveCustomer()
    {
        $customer =  $this->customerData;
        $customer->setWebsiteId(1);
        $customer->setFirstname($data['firstname']);
        $customer->setLastname($data['lastname']);
        $customer->setPassword($data['password']);
        $customer->setGender($data['gender']);
        $customer->setDob($data['dob']);
        $customer->setEmail($data['email']); 
        $customer->setCustomAttribute('dice_sum', '23');
        $customer->setCustomAttribute('place_of_birth','joan');
        $this->customer->save($customer);

    }        
}
```

Comment: still not working

Comment: have you use service provide `RepositoryInterface`?.

Comment: yes i've used it