# Save customer attribute programmatically in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, php, attributes

I'm trying to save the value of some custom customer attributes programmatically.

I have seen a few examples and everyone is proposing to create a controller for this. But I would like to save the attribute value without creating a controller and without calling it from the Object Manager.

In Magento 1 the code was this and it was enough to reload the page for it to work:

```
$customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()
$customer->setmyattribute(date('Y'));
$customer->save();
```

In my Magento 2 this is my code that i tried but not work:

```
namespace vendor\module\Block;

class SaveData
{

protected $customer;

protected $customerRepository;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer $customer,
    \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository
)
{
    $this->customer = $customer;
    $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
}

public function saveDatagruppo()
{   
    $customer_id = 3;

    $customer_repo = $this->customerRepository->create();
    $customer = $customer_repo->getById($customer_id);

    // get Custome Attribute value
    $cust_att = $customer->getCustomAttribute("datagruppo")->getValue();
    print_r($cust_att);

    //set custom Attribute value
    $add_id = "2021";
    $customer->setCustomAttribute("datagruppo",$add_id);
    $customer_repo->save($customer);

}
}
```

And this is the code in frontend

```
$blockPHPCuong = $block->getLayout()->createBlock('\vendor\module\Block\SaveData');
$blockPHPCuong->saveDatagruppo();
```

How can I do so that I can save my attribute on page load?
Thanks

Comment: check this link --- https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/200365/85907

Comment: @MohitPatel Man i see and i tried but not work. Please see my update question!

Comment: you save data in code write in block file like $custom->save(); . not call in other .phtml file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Try this code

```
$customer_id = 3;

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerRepository = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface');
$customer = $customerRepository->getById($customer_id);

// get Custome Attribute value
$cust_att = $customer->getCustomAttribute("datagruppo")->getValue();
print_r($cust_att);

//set custom Attribute value
$add_id = "Value here";
$customer->setCustomAttribute("datagruppo",$add_id);
$customerRepository->save($customer);
```

> Other Way

```
<?php

namespace vendor\module\Block;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class SaveData extends Template
{
    protected $customer;

    protected $customerRepository;

    public function __construct(
        Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer $customer,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerFactory $customerFactory,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->customer = $customer;
        $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
    }
    public function saveDatagruppo()
    {
        $customer_id = 3;

        $customer_repo = $this->customerRepository->create();
        $customer_repo = $this->customerRepository->getById($customer_id);

        //set custom Attribute value
        $add_id = "2022";
        $customer_repo->setCustomAttribute("datagruppo",$add_id);
        $customer_repo->save();
        //$this->customerRepository->save($customer_repo);
    }
}
```

***I Hope This Helps You.***

Answer (score -1):

Much easier, guys

```
$customer->setSomeAttribute('val');
$customer->getResource()->saveAttribute($customer, 'some_attribute');
```